# Алгоритм масштабирования изображения с изменением соотношения сторон

Tags: c#, алгоритм, масштабирование

Мне нужно подогнать изображение под формат 30 на 30 пикселей, при этом в зависимости от размера исходного изображения уменьшить его или увеличить, соотношение сторон исходного изображения не важно. 
Например берем символ (букву, цифру или знак препинания) в виде изображения произвольного размера и на выходе получаем изображение 30 на 30 пикселей, где этот символ можно распознать.
Пишу на С#
Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм или встроенный метод, который мне поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если устраивает деформированное изображение, то, например, можно использовать класс [System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) из Windows Forms.

```
// Загружаем исходное изображение
var image1 = new Bitmap("image.jpg");

// Масштабируем до нужного размера
var image2 = new Bitmap(image1, 30, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

А в чём сложность?

Ищете, что у вас больше — длина или ширина. Пусть большее из длины и ширины равно `s`. Соскалируйте картинку с коэффициентом `30/s`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Мне нужно получить картинку символа, где верхняя строчка пикселей была бы заполнена и так со всеми четырьмя сторонами, то есть картинка должна быть обрезана так чтобы не было пустоты ни с одной стороны. Я не могу понять как растягивать или сжимать изображения так, чтобы оно всегда было 30 на 30.

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c604625/v604625676/11b04/exnM9Cn3ERE.jpg исходное

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c604625/v604625676/11b0b/YO-sco7M5Rw.jpg полученное

Comment: 30 на 30 не будет. Когда вы отскалируете, одно из измерений будет 30, а другое меньше. Дополните белыми или прозрачными пикселями с боков (или сверху/снизу).

Comment: В том то и дело, что на выходе мне нужно растянутое изображение, но без белых или прозрачных пикселей сверху или снизу.

Comment: Но это же деформирует символ! Вас это устраивает?

Comment: Да, устраивает. Мне это нужно чтобы потом скормить нейросети, но не суть.

Comment: Тогда скалируйте по ширине в 30/w, по высоте в 30/h раз.